# CSS Expected a Selector for Style Rule for classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem:**

I'm trying to remove padding/margin to the right and left of bootstrap columns, col-md-* and col-xs-* in Bootstrap 3. However, the class that I created to do this is not working.
I'm using the below CSS code for this:

```
.no-gutters > [class^="col-"],
.no-gutters > [class*="col-"]
{
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

I'm using visual studio 10 as my IDE and it shows the message "Unexpected character sequence. Expected a selector for the style rule." at the '[' brackets.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: The HTML is something like below:
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 no-gutters">
        <asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sould make like this.

```
<div class="no-gutters">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
 <asp:Panel> </asp:Panel> 
</div>
</div>
```

Then this Css will work.

```
.no-gutters > [class^="col-"],
.no-gutters > [class*="col-"]
{
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: On a separate note is that the only way to remove the default bootstrap padding, and is this one an optimum way?

Comment: I don't know is this is the optimum way.
But any way we are selecting inside class .no-gutters so this will affect only under this children element